# How can i get elements parent at point?

Tags: org-mode

```
(defun print-org-element()
  (interactive)
  (message (format "%s" (org-element-type (org-element-at-point))))
  (message (org-element-property :title (org-element-at-point)))
  (message (org-element-property :parent (org-element-at-point))))
```

If caret is on headline, why this func can't print it's parent?

Answer (score 2):

From the Org Element API at https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html.

> Unless point is on a headline, both functions indirectly return all parents of the value within the current section[footnote], through :parent property.

The footnote says:

> Thus, org-element-at-point cannot return the parent of a headline. Nevertheless, headlines are context free elements: it is efficient to move to parent headline (e.g., with org-up-heading-safe) before analyzing it.

Comment: Weird. Why wouldn't they make it easy to access headlines parent? It seems like common use case. So is there a better way to find headlines parent, then searching backwards until i find string starting with less stars then the headline?

Comment: You could also follow the suggestion and use org-up-heading-safe.  There might be other functions which better fit your use case.

Comment: @ame90 The `:parent` property needs the whole parse tree (i.e., the value of `(org-element-parse-buffer)`) to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

`org-element-at` and `org-element-context` are often used in org source code because they give quite reliable, precise, and comprehensive information about the local structure of an org document.
Counting the occurrence of both in `org.el` gives the number 56 for `org-20180115`.

That precious information comes at a cost. The org-element parser is quite complicated and takes longer than a regexp-based search.

Therefore one needs to delimit the parsing for frequently run functions to a small local part of the document. The section headings are the most appropriate and most narrow boundaries for such parts.

The following slow variant `my-org-element-at-point` does not have the limitations of `org-element-at-point` but it is slower because it parses the whole Org buffer.

```el
(defun my-org-element-neighborhood-p (element position &optional greater-element)
  "Return non-nil if POSITION is within the bounds of ELEMENT.
If GREATER-ELEMENT is non-nil the result is only non-nil
if ELEMENT is contained in GREATER-ELEMENT.
If the result is non-nil it is actually ELEMENT."
  (let ((b (org-element-property :begin element))
    (e (org-element-property :end element)))
    (and
     (<= b position)
     (>= e position)
     (or (null greater-element)
     (and (>= b (org-element-property :begin greater-element))
          (<= e (org-element-property :end greater-element))))
     element)))

(defun my-org-element-at-point (&optional point)
  "Slow but more complete version of `org-element-at-point`."
  (unless point (setq point (point)))
  (let ((tree (org-element-parse-buffer))
    el-at)
    (org-element-map tree org-element-all-elements
      (lambda (el)
    (setq el-at (or (my-org-element-neighborhood-p el point el-at) el-at))))
    el-at))
```